# Connection Sharing and Structuring of Model Objects

Tags: php, mongodb, oop

I'm writing my own OOP framework, partially as a learning exercise, but knowing this codebase isn't going to disappear - only evolve as I learn. Below is some psuedocode of what my setup looks like. In this setup, how would I share DB connections? Do a ctrl+f for "connection" to find the places in the code I'm specifically unsure of how to structure.

A routing file would look like this:

```
switch($urlParameters['action']){
    case 'lading': 
        //etc etc
        break;

    case 'userCP':
        //etc etc
        break;

    case 'dashboard':
    default:
        $page = new dashboard();
        $page->route($urlParameters);
        break;
}
```

A page would look like

```
<?php
abstract class page{ // Page is a mixture of controller and view. Most view logic is frontend, so I do all my controller-view logic here

    public var $models;

    public var $session;
    public var $user;

    function __construct(){
        $this->models = new models();

        $this->session = $this->models->session(new MongoID($_COOKIE['session'])); // Plus some code to prevent session hijacking

        $this->user = $this->models->users($this->session->userID);
    }

    function outputMongoData(){} // Wrapper function used by pages to output Mongo datatypes as regular json (Dates to RFC, IDs to string, rounding floats, etc)

    function template($file, $data){} // This uses output buffering and extract() to use php its self as the templating language. 
}


class dashboard extends page{
    public var $dashboardView;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->dashboardView = $this->models->dashboardView($this->user->dashboardViewID);
    }

    function route($urlParams){
        $this->session->updatePageViewCountOrSomething();

        echo $this->template('dashboard.php', [
            'importantData' => $this->dashboardView->someTypeOfDataFromDashboardView,
            'viewCount'     => $this->session->pageViewCount
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the models look like

```
<?php
class models{
    private var $cache = [
        'users' => [],
        'dashboardViews' => [],
        'sessions' => [],
    ];
    // Cache to prevent collisions since we're doing save() vs individual updates, plus saves overhead of querying multiple times (potentially hundreds of times for certain models)

    function __construct(){
        // Potential connection sharing stuff here
    }

    private function modelFactory($collection, $modelName, $identifier){
        $stringID = (string) $identifier;
        if(!isset($this->cache[$collection][$stringID])){
            $this->cache[$collection][$stringID] = new $modelName($identifier);
        }

        return $this->cache[$collection][$stringID];
    }


    public function session(MongoID $sessionID){
        return $this->modelFactory('sessions', 'session', $sessionID);
    }

    public function user(MongoID $userID){
        return $this->modelFactory('users', 'user', $userID);
    }

    public function dashboardView(MongoID $dashboardViewID){
        return $this->modelFactory('dashboardViews', 'dashboardView', $dashboardViewID);
    }
}

abstract class model{
    public var $db;
    public var $collection;

    private var $data = [];

    function __construct($collectionName){
        $this->db = // ??? Not sure how to connect so that I don't have a new connection for every single model..

        $this->collection = $this->db->{$collectionName};
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->collection->save($this->data);
    }

    function __get($fieldName){
        return $this->data[$fieldName]; // if isset, etc etc
    }

}

class session extends model{
    // Explanation of schema here
    function __construct(MongoID $sessionID){
        parent::__construct('sessions');

        $this->data = $this->collection->findOne(['_id' => $sessionID]); // or if not found, create..
    }

    function updatePageViewCountOrSomething(){
        $this->data['pageViewCount'] += 1;
        $this->data['orSomething'] = ['something' => 'or another'];
    }
}

class dashboardView extends model{
    // Explanation of schema here

    function __construct(MongoID $dashboardViewID){
        parent::__construct('dashboardViews');

        $this->data = $this->collection->findOne(['_id' => $sessionID]); // or if not found, create..
    }

    function addColumns(){}

    function reorderColumns($newOrder){}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific targeted programming question? As it is written, it's vaguely asking for opinions about your design, which isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: As in the post - "A) In this setup, how would I share DB connections?" - I'll go ahead and edit it to be more prevalent @WiredPrairie

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like the `models` class is functioning as a factory for your model instances. In that case, you could use it as the connection container and then pass the appropriate `MongoCollection` instance to each model class instead of the collection name.

I'll also note that in the PHP driver, there is not really a concern with constructing multiple `MongoClient` objects. The driver uses persistent connections internally, so constructing five `MongoClient` instances all with the same host/port/user/password combination will still only create a single network socket behind the scenes. You can test this out for yourself using the example in [this slide](https://speakerdeck.com/jmikola/dos-and-donts-of-mongodb?slide=8) and the one following.

Some general concerns with your `model` implementation:

- `$data` is private to the base `model` class, but you access it in the child classes. It should probably be protected.
- Waiting until `__destruct()` to save an object back to the database seems like a bad idea, as it could happen at the end of the script or sometime earlier if the object is garbage-collected. Having a predictable point in the application to write data seems preferable.
- Instead of using this model for persisting session data, you can read up on the [SessionHandlerInterface](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) in PHP 5.4+. That allows you to implement a custom storage backend (MongoDB in this case) to be used by the standard PHP session API (e.g. `$SESSION`).

A great starting point before creating a framework (even as a thought exercise), would be to read up on design patterns. Anthony Ferrara's [blog](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/search/label/Design%20Patterns) is a great resource and starting point for the subject. I would also suggest learning about dependency injection and service containers, as that's very relevant to your original question about sharing a common resource (e.g. database connection). Fabien Potencier did a great [blog series](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) on the subject. The article is a few years old and references the Symfony 1.x implementation (Symfony2 is the current model he uses), but the early posts will likely serve as a useful introduction.